# C++ Using ASCII instead of a letter in a enum

Tags: c++, enums

i have a enum:

```
enum Items {
    PAC = 'C', GHOST = '@', FRUIT = 'o', POINTS = '.', WALL = 'w', EMPTY = ' ', UNDEFINED = '+'
} fieldItems;
```

And i want to change w with the 178 of the ascii table. I know how i assign it: char w = 178;
But how do i say the w of the enum that it is a char?

Comment: It isn't ascii.  Hard-coding character codes from code page 437 doesn't exactly port that well.

Comment: when you use it, by assigning the value to an unsigned char, it will represent the correct value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just:

```
WALL = 178
```

If you want to control the underlying type of the `enum`, you should use

```
enum Items : char { ... };
```

anyways. Note that only the enum type `Items` has a single underlying type, not each value. You can not tell the compiler that `WALL` is of a specific type.

Comment: This gives me a weird error: warning: scoped enums only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]

Comment: @AnnoyedGuy That's not weird, it's just true: You need C++11 to have the above way to control the enum's type. If you can't use C++11, just use `WALL = 178`, as it won't make any real difference if you use other ways like `'\xB2'` or `char(178)` - the result will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a decimal-escape for character literals, but there's a hex escape:

```
WALL='\xB2'
```